# How to obtain sheet names from XLS files without loading the whole file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I'm currently using pandas to read an Excel file and present its sheet names to the user, so he can select which sheet he would like to use. The problem is that the files are really big (70 columns x 65k rows), taking up to 14s to load on a notebook (the same data in a CSV file is taking 3s).

My code in panda goes like this:

```
xls = pandas.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = xls.sheet_names
```

I tried xlrd before, but obtained similar results. This was my code with xlrd:

```
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheets = xls.sheet_names
```

So, can anybody suggest a faster way to retrieve the sheet names from an Excel file than reading the whole file?

Comment: How long does it take to open such a file in Excel directly?

Comment: @DocBrown About 4s if Excel if already open (Excel Starter 2010)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

you can use the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) library and open the workbook with the "on_demand=True" flag, so that the sheets won't be loaded automaticaly.

Than you can retrieve the sheet names in a similar way to pandas:

```
import xlrd
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'<path_to_your_excel_file>', on_demand=True)
print xls.sheet_names() # <- remeber: xlrd sheet_names is a function, not a property
```

Comment: the xlrd documentation says this works only with BIFF >= 5.0. It does not work for me, and if I ask xls.biff_version it says "0" which seems strange (impossible?). Any idea what may be happening?

Comment: You could also pass the result from `xlrd.open_workbook` to `pandas.ExcelFile` and interact with the object as you used to: `xls = pandas.ExcelFile(xlrd.open_workbook(path, on_demand=True))`

Comment: This is too slow just for sheet names.

Comment: it spent 11 seconds for 5MB file. It seems it loads whole file

Comment: @rluts I agree, this approach is still very slow. Is there a better solution?

Comment: This loads the whole file. It's not answering the actual question

Answer (score 22):

From my research with the standard / popular libs this hasn't been implemented as of **2020** for `xlsx` / `xls` but you can do this for `xlsb`. Either way these solutions should give you vast performance improvements. for `xls`, `xlsx`, `xlsb`.

Below was benchmarked on a ~10Mb `xlsx`, `xlsb` file.

#### `xlsx, xls`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def get_sheetnames_xlsx(filepath):
    wb = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=True, keep_links=False)
    return wb.sheetnames
```

*Benchmark:* ~ **14x speed improvement**

```
# get_sheetnames_xlsx vs pd.read_excel
225 ms ± 6.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.25 s ± 140 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### `xlsb`

```
from pyxlsb import open_workbook

def get_sheetnames_xlsb(filepath):
  with open_workbook(filepath) as wb:
     return wb.sheets
```

*Benchmark:* ~ **56x speed improvement**

```
# get_sheetnames_xlsb vs pd.read_excel
96.4 ms ± 1.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5.36 s ± 162 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Notes:*

- This is a good resource -
  http://www.python-excel.org/
- `xlrd` is no longer maintained as of 2020

Answer (score 18):

I have tried xlrd, pandas, openpyxl and other such libraries and all of them seem to take exponential time as the file size increase as it reads the entire file. The other solutions mentioned above where they used 'on_demand' did not work for me. The following function works for xlsx files.

```
def get_sheet_details(file_path):
    sheets = []
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file_path)[-1])[0]
    # Make a temporary directory with the file name
    directory_to_extract_to = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)
    os.mkdir(directory_to_extract_to)

    # Extract the xlsx file as it is just a zip file
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
    zip_ref.close()

    # Open the workbook.xml which is very light and only has meta data, get sheets from it
    path_to_workbook = os.path.join(directory_to_extract_to, 'xl', 'workbook.xml')
    with open(path_to_workbook, 'r') as f:
        xml = f.read()
        dictionary = xmltodict.parse(xml)
        for sheet in dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet']:
            sheet_details = {
                'id': sheet['sheetId'], # can be @sheetId for some versions
                'name': sheet['name'] # can be @name
            }
            sheets.append(sheet_details)

    # Delete the extracted files directory
    shutil.rmtree(directory_to_extract_to)
    return sheets
```

Since all xlsx are basically zipped files, we extract the underlying xml data and read sheet names from the workbook directly which takes a fraction of a second as compared to the library functions.

*Benchmarking: (On a 6mb xlsx file with 4 sheets)*

**Pandas, xlrd:** 12 seconds

**openpyxl:** 24 seconds

**Proposed method:** 0.4 seconds

Comment: You need to configure a bunch of Django settings to use this. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Skirting around the Django requirements, I am also met with this error: `File is not a zip file` My file is a Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls) Maybe it doesn't work for old versions of Excel

Comment: @CoreyLevinson, As mentioned in the post, this works for xlsx files only as .xlsx files use Office Open XML, which is a zipped XML format. .xls files use the BIFF format. I have not yet come across a requirement for xls file. But if you can find a workaround to unzip and read inner content, I think this approach will work for you as well. Also, no django settings have to be altered I only use media_cdn or BASE_DIR and create a temp dir somewhere relative to it for all this.

Comment: Your code saved hours of efforts, these code has one catch that I had to fix which is basically if Excel has only one sheet it throws an error which I fixed using these one-liner 

`sheets1 = dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet'] if not(isinstance(sheets1, list)): sheets1 =[sheets1]`

Comment: @piyushmandovra I did the same fix and came back here to add a comment about it only to find your comment here lol.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [dhwanil-shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192804/dhwanil-shah)'s answer, I find this to be the most efficient:

```py
import os
import re
import zipfile

def get_excel_sheet_names(file_path):
    sheets = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref: xml = zip_ref.read("xl/workbook.xml").decode("utf-8")
    for s_tag in  re.findall("<sheet [^>]*", xml) : sheets.append(  re.search('name="[^"]*', s_tag).group(0)[6:])
    return sheets

sheets  = get_excel_sheet_names("Book1.xlsx")
print(sheets)
# prints: "['Sheet1', 'my_sheet 2']"
```

**xlsb working altenative**

```py
import os
import re
import zipfile

def get_xlsb_sheet_names(file_path):
    sheets = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref: xml = zip_ref.read("docProps/app.xml").decode("utf-8")
        xml=grep("<TitlesOfParts>.*</TitlesOfParts>", xml)
        for s_tag in  re.findall("<vt:lpstr>.*</vt:lpstr>", xml) : sheets.append(  re.search('>.*<', s_tag).group(0))[1:-1])

    return sheets
```

Advantages are :

- speed
- simple code, easy to adapt
- no temporary file or directory creation (all in memory)
- using only core libs

To be improved:

- **regex parsing** (Not sure how it would behave if the sheet name contained a double quote ["] )

Answer (score 3):

By combining @Dhwanil shah's answer with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828581/12336205) I wrote code that is also compatible with xlsx files that have only one sheet:

```
def get_sheet_ids(file_path):
sheet_names = []
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    xml = zip_ref.open(r'xl/workbook.xml').read()
    dictionary = xmltodict.parse(xml)

    if not isinstance(dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet'], list):
        sheet_names.append(dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet']['@name'])
    else:
        for sheet in dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet']:
            sheet_names.append(sheet['@name'])
return sheet_names
```

Answer (score 1):

Python code adaptation with full pathlib path filename passed (e.g., ('c:\xml\file.xlsx')).
From [Dhwanil shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192804/dhwanil-shah) answer, without Django method used to create a temp dir.

```
import xmltodict
import shutil
import zipfile


def get_sheet_details(filename):
    sheets = []
    # Make a temporary directory with the file name
    directory_to_extract_to = (filename.with_suffix(''))
    directory_to_extract_to.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    # Extract the xlsx file as it is just a zip file
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
    zip_ref.close()
    # Open the workbook.xml which is very light and only has meta data, get sheets from it
    path_to_workbook = directory_to_extract_to / 'xl' / 'workbook.xml'
    with open(path_to_workbook, 'r') as f:
        xml = f.read()
        dictionary = xmltodict.parse(xml)
        for sheet in dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet']:
            sheet_details = {
                'id': sheet['@sheetId'],  # can be sheetId for some versions
                'name': sheet['@name']  # can be name
            }
            sheets.append(sheet_details)
    # Delete the extracted files directory
    shutil.rmtree(directory_to_extract_to)
    return sheets
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard libraries only:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from zipfile import Path as ZipPath


def sheet_names(path: Path) -> tuple[str, ...]:
    xml: bytes = ZipPath(path, at="xl/workbook.xml").read_bytes()
    root: ET.Element = ET.fromstring(xml)
    namespace = m.group(0) if (m := re.match(r"\{.*\}", root.tag)) else ""
    return tuple(x.attrib["name"] for x in root.findall(f"./{namespace}sheets/") if x.tag == f"{namespace}sheet")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to read excel sheet names :

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'<path-to-filename>') 
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

To read data from specific sheet in excel using pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(io = '<path-to-file>', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name = 'Report', header=7, skipfooter=1).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

XLSB & XLSM solution. Inspired by Cedric Bonjour.

```
import re
import zipfile

def get_sheet_names(file_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref: 
        xml = zip_ref.read("docProps/app.xml").decode("utf-8")
    xml = re.findall("<TitlesOfParts>.*</TitlesOfParts>", xml)[0]
    sheets = re.findall(">([^>]*)<", xml)
    sheets = list(filter(None,sheets))
    return sheets
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution for handling all of `xlsx`, `xlsm`, and `xlsb` can be further derived from [Cedric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250024/how-to-obtain-sheet-names-from-xls-files-without-loading-the-whole-file/71741449#71741449)

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import html
import re
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path


def _get_xlsx_names(file_path: Path) -> list[str]:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        xml = zip_ref.read("xl/workbook.xml").decode("utf-8")
    return [
        html.unescape(sheet_name)
        for sheet_name in re.findall(r'<sheet.*?name="([^"]+?)".*?/>', xml)
    ]


def _get_xlsm_names(file_path: Path) -> list[str]:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        xml = zip_ref.read("docProps/app.xml").decode("utf-8")
    return [
        html.unescape(sheet_name)
        # Find all titles
        for titles in re.findall(r"<TitlesOfParts>(.+?)</TitlesOfParts>", xml)
        # Find all sheet names in titles
        for sheet_name in re.findall(r"<vt:lpstr>(.+?)</vt:lpstr>", titles)
    ]


def get_sheet_names(file_path: str | Path) -> list[str]:
    file_path = Path(file_path)
    if file_path.suffix == ".xlsx":
        return _get_xlsx_names(file_path)
    if file_path.suffix in [".xlsm", ".xlsb"]:
        return _get_xlsm_names(file_path)
    msg = f"Unsupported file extension '{file_path.suffix}' found."
    raise NotImplementedError(msg)
```

Regarding the usage of `"` (and `<`, `>`, `&`) in sheet names, from my limited experimentation:

- `xlsx` files replace `"` with `&quot;`
- `xlsx`, `xlsm`, and `xlsb` replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;`, and `&` with `&amp;`

`html.unescape` can solve all of these issues for us, and we're still only using the standard library.

Tweaking our regexes to use capture groups can help simplify our python syntax.

While this works on my machine for my limited testing, all this use of regex to quickly parse xml does put me on edge.

Answer (score -4):

you can also use

```
data=pd.read_excel('demanddata.xlsx',sheet_name='oil&gas')
print(data)
```

Here demanddata is the name of your file
oil&gas is one of your sheet name.Let there may be n number of sheet in your worksheet.Just Give the Name of the sheet which you like to fetch at Sheet_name="Name of Your required sheet"

Comment: I'd recommend explaining why this method would be faster than his current approach, or showing that it is faster in certain cases. (Provide more evidence in general) This may be a great answer, but providing more basis as to why it is great will help readers evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks @Xgongiveittoya .Thats a good suggestion & I will do it.

Comment: This does not do what the OP requested, namely to fetch the names of the sheets from a workbook (initially unknown). Instead, this extracts the data from a sheet that is already known.