# Need to append multiple Sheet from multiple excel, but also need to skip excel which not have that sheet name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append multiple sheets from multiple excel. But a challenge I have is to skip the excel which not has that sheet name.
here, Sheet name is variable..i.e `softcode` can be entered manually.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users')
files=os.listdir()
print("files read")
Sheet_count=int(input('No. of sheet to append: '))
sheet_list=[]
sheet_New=[]
for i in range(0,sheet_count):
    sheet_name=input('Enter the MO class to merge: ')
    sheet_list.append(sheet_name)
    sheet_New.append(sheet_name)
print(sheet_New)
for j in range(len(sheet_New)):
    sheet_New[j]=pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    for k in range(len(sheet_list)):
                df_temp = load_workbook(f, sheet_list[k])
                sheet_New[k] = sheet_New[k].append(df_temp)
```

the only challenge I have to skip the excel file which not has that sheet name

Comment: use sheet_names() to find if file have sheet name that you need

Comment: can you pls add .. some piece of code

Comment: you can find all you need on stackoverflow just make some search:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250024/how-to-obtain-sheet-names-from-xls-files-without-loading-the-whole-file

Comment: not getting what i looking for

Comment: you need to append all this sheets into new excel file? Sheet name is one item or list of items?