# Store pd.readcsv Sheet name

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to store the sheet name from a csv as a string variable?

Something like this maybe:

```py
path=r"file_path\file.csv"
df=read.csv(path)

sheet_name=df.sheet
```

Comment: Try importing `xlrd`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250416/8748098) Link will help you I think

Comment: `pd.ExcelFile()` allows you to store sheetnames.