# How to read excel sheets with varying names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I am currently trying to create a dataframe by reading specific sheet from about 20 spreadsheets. However, some of the spreadsheets have a different name to the tab I want to get data from.

I know that the tabs are named 'A' or 'AA'

I would like to know if there is a way I can pass the two names in the pandas read_excel as the names vary in some sheet. I am essentially looking for something like

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = 'A' or 'AA')
```

if I pass the two names with an or, it returns an error. Is there a way for read_excel function to get data from a sheet named either 'A' or 'AA' in the excel file?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not work with python but I guess the logic would be get the sheet names from the excel file and then checking if it has "A" or "AA" and then passing that name? See if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250024/how-to-obtain-sheet-names-from-xls-files-without-loading-the-whole-file) gets you started.

Comment: Are those sheets containing only single tab in each? can you use index instead name like `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [try except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) method, to first try opening sheet `A` and if that fails try opening sheet `AA`:

```
try:
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 'A')
except:
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 'AA')
```

This won't have the desired outcome if there is a workbook with both an `A` and an `AA` sheet name, or if there is a workbook without either sheet names.

Comment: I'd recommend making the `except` catch specific exceptions. That's too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Try and see if this works:

```
# this reads in the data and allows access to the sheet names
# also memory efficient
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')

# iterate to find sheet name that matches 
data = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name = [name for name in xls.sheet_names
                                        if name in ('A','AA')])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator does something completely different to do with booleans.

Try this

```
try:
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='A')
except:
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='AA')
```

This will try to open a sheet with the name 'A', and if there is none and pandas throws an error, it will open the sheet named 'AA'